# Contact Form forms id

Tags: contact-form-7

I created a form on my local environment which I needed to use on the live site. I followed Contact Form documentation for exporting importing the forms:

https://contactform7.com/faq/how-can-i-export-import-contact-form-data/

Forms are imported correctly, however, with different ids. I need to keep the same id, because I use them to show the forms.

Why does CF imports the forms with different ids?

Solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually databases tend to generate unique ids, try changing that to a set variable and assign a specific value.

Comment: Thanks! How do I do that ?

Comment: What kind of data base is it? Do you have access to it? I assume due to wordpress being open-source you should have some idea. It's a little hard to tell you anything too specific if I don't see the problem or knowing how it looks on your end. If you give me more information I might be able to give a better answer.